# How do I conditionally output eslint results to a file using npm scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, eslint

I am trying to make a simple npm script to run eslint and check if it's in CI or not and output the results to a file if it is.

This works to output the results to the terminal:

```
"lint": "eslint src --cache --format $(if [ -z ${SOMEVAR} ]; then echo \"stylish\"; else echo \"checkstyle\"; fi)",
```

But I want to save them to a file if there is an ENV var present using `> checkstyle.xml`

Is there a way to tack this onto that command? I've tried several ways, but no luck getting the file to output.

**Edit:**
I was able to get this working by adding `--color | tee checkstyle.xml` which writes the xml file regardless of ENV var value and displays a colorized version to terminal. This is not ideal, but does work. Open to other ideas though.

I found this great chart that shows what combos of output you can use together to achieve this: https://askubuntu.com/a/731237/541276

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
if [ "$somevar" ]; then exec >checkstyle.xml; fi; eslint ...
```

Comment: That does work duh. I am ideally trying to only do a single `if` and have the `--format` value and the output in a single condition. But thanks either way